# Android push notification stop repeating sound on activity resume

Tags: android

I am implementing an app that receive push notifications. I have used flag `Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT` to continuously play sound until user drag notification panel. But I want to stop the sound on app resume rather than on dragging notification panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_INSISTENT), for notifications with `FLAG_INSISTENT` audio will be repeated until the notification is cancelled or the notification window is opened.

So when you resume your activity you can cancel your notification. if you want it to stay in the notification window, then redisplay it again without sound and the insistent flag.